# Java reflection with enums and interfaces

Tags: java, events, gwt, reflection, enums

I'm working on some code for a User Interface. In this code there is a generic interface like the following:

```
public interface DataValue<T>
{
  public String getName();

  public T getValue();

  public String getDescription();

}
```

Now, this interface is implemented by many Enumerations across the code and it is used in a hover event controller for values in the interface that can be represented by the DataValue interface. I realized that there were some warnings in this controller so I unsuccessfully tried to find a way to remove them. The controller class looks like the following:

```
public class HintController implements ItemHoverHandler
{

private final Class<? extends Enum> theEnumClass;

public HintController(Class<? extends Enum> enumClass)
{
    theEnumClass = enumClass;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onItemHover(ItemHoverEvent event)
{
  FormItem formItem = event.getItem();
  Enum<?> enumValue =
     Enum.valueOf(theEnumClass, (String)formItem.getValue());
  String prompt = (enumValue instanceof DataValue)
     ? getPromptForDataValue((DataValue)enumValue)
     : null;
  formItem.setPrompt(prompt);
}


 private String getPromptForDataValue(DataValue<?> dataValue)
 {
  return "<b>" + dataValue.getName() + "</b><br /><br />"
     + dataValue.getDescription();
 }
}
```

Of course this implementation has some rawType warnings which I am not able to fix. If I parametrize the field with ? wildcard it will show a bounds exception. My closes "attempt" was when I tried to change the type of the field and construction parameter tom something like this:

```
 public class HintController implements ItemHoverHandler
 {

   private final Enum<? extends DataValue<?>> theEnumClass;

   public HintController(Enum<? extends DataValue<?>>enumClass)
   {
    theEnumClass = enumClass;
   }


    @Override
    public void onItemHover(ItemHoverEvent event)
    {
     FormItem formItem = event.getItem();
     Enum<? extends DataValue<?>>enumValue =
        Enum.valueOf(theEnumClass.getDeclaringClass(),formItem.getValue().toString());
     String prompt = (enumValue instanceof DataValue)
        ? getPromptForDataValue((DataValue<?>)enumValue)
       : null;
     formItem.setPrompt(prompt);
    }


    private String getPromptForDataValue(DataValue<?> dataValue)
    {
      return "<b>" + dataValue.getName() + "</b><br /><br />"
        + dataValue.getDescription();
    }
 }
```

But of course, it failed because I couldn't find a way to actually send a reference of that type, because they are enumerations and I can't instantiate them. I think there should be a proper way to do this  would be grateful if someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the warnings go away by putting a real type parameter on the `HintController`:

```
public class HintController<E extends Enum<E>> implements ItemHoverHandler {

    private final Class<E> theEnumClass;

    public HintController(Class<E> enumClass) {
        theEnumClass = enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemHover(ItemHoverEvent event) {
        FormItem formItem = event.getItem();
        E enumValue = Enum.valueOf(theEnumClass, (String) formItem.getValue());
        String prompt = (enumValue instanceof DataValue) ? getPromptForDataValue((DataValue<?>) enumValue) : null;
        formItem.setPrompt(prompt);
    }

    private String getPromptForDataValue(DataValue<?> dataValue) {
        return "<b>" + dataValue.getName() + "</b><br /><br />" + dataValue.getDescription();
    }

}
```

Whether that is plausible given the impact on other classes which use it, i cannot say. I would imagine it would be - anywhere that creates one already has some idea about the type of the `enumClass` constructor parameter, which it could simply propagate to the `HintController`. Places that use it in other ways can always call it a `HintController<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it seems like your problems could be solved by making `HintController` generic:

```
public class HintController<T extends Enum<T>> implements ItemHoverHandler {

    private final T theEnumClass;

    //and so on...
```

Note, however, that `theEnumClass` is probably misnamed as it would just point to an instance of the enum `T`. You would probably want to use `Class<T>` instead. That would allow you to call methods reflective methods like [`getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this should be an interface.  It seems like DataValue should actually be a *class*.

```
public class DataValue< T extends Enum >
{
    public String getName() { ... }
    public String getValue() { ... } 
    public String getDescription() { ... }
}
```

If you do that, then just put the DataValue in the hover event -- and then get the information directly from it.